# Why Cocos Creator engine file is not called on the browser?

Tags: cocos2d-js, cocoscreator

Non-Latin characters are not truncated properly so I modified the **fragmentText()** function to truncate on white space. file is in:

> "C:\CocosCreator\resources\engine\cocos2d\core\label\CCTextUtils.js"

```
fragmentText: function (stringToken, allWidth, maxWidth, measureText) {
    return "function called";
}
```

The problem is that I see the changes in Cocos Creator editor and the text is truncated as I want, but I see no effect on the browser as the function is never called.

Why the function is not called when I build?

P.S: I use Cocos Creator 1.10 but also have 2.1.1 installed in *C:\CocosCreator_2.1.1*

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forget to recompile the engine.

Check the step 1.3 on the website and try again.
[1.3 Change and Build](https://docs.cocos.com/creator/manual/en/advanced-topics/engine-customization.html)